# jQuery Validate plugin remote rule doesn't return boolean

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate, jsonp

I have to call a servlet with remote field in jQuery validator to check if already exists inserted username. The problem is that I have to call it in JSONP and that it doesn't return me neither a boolean nor a string, but a Json with possible alternatives. Any help?

Using this method, it always says that a user already exists!

```
    function parseUser(a){return a}

    $.validator.addMethod("checkUserUnique", function(value, element) {
    $.ajax({
        url:'myservletJSONP.do',
        data: {'username':function(){return $("#registration-form1 :input[name='username']").val()}},
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'parseUser',
        success: function(data){
            if(data[0].result=='exist'){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        },
        error: function(er){
            console.log("error: "+er);
        }
    })

});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

that's the answer:

```
    $.validator.addMethod("remoteValidator", function(value, element, param) {
        var previous = this.previousValue(element);
        if (!this.settings.messages[element.name] ) {
            this.settings.messages[element.name] = {};
        }
        previous.originalMessage = this.settings.messages[element.name].remote;
        this.settings.messages[element.name].remote = previous.message;
        param = typeof param === "string" && {url:param} || param;
        if ( previous.old === value ) {
            return previous.valid;
        }
        previous.old = value;
        var validator = this;
        this.startRequest(element);
        var data = {};
        data[element.name] = value;
        $.ajax($.extend(true, {
            url: param.url,
            data: function(){return param.data || data}(),
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: false,
            jsonpCallback: param.callback,
            success: function( response ) {
                var valid = param.checkValidity(response) 
                if ( valid ) {
                    var submitted = validator.formSubmitted;
                    validator.prepareElement(element);
                    validator.formSubmitted = submitted;
                    validator.successList.push(element);
                    delete validator.invalid[element.name];
                    validator.showErrors();
                } else {
                    var errors = {};
                    var message = validator.settings.messages[element.name]["remoteValidator"];
                    errors[element.name] = message;
                    validator.invalid[element.name] = true;
                    validator.showErrors(errors);                       
                }
                previous.valid = valid;
                validator.stopRequest(element, valid);
            }
        }, param));
        return "pending";
});
```

you can call it adding to your rule this rows:

```
remoteValidator: {'url':'myServlet','checkValidity': function(resp){if(someStuff)return true; return false}                                         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `remote` rule is looking for a boolean.

If you cannot achieve this, then the alternative is to create & use a custom rule instead.  Within your custom method, you can write any function you want... run your `ajax`, test your result, and simply `return true` to pass a validated field.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("myRule", function(value, element) { 
    // your ajax
    // if ( your ajax result == "something" ) {
        // return false; // represents failed validation
    //} else {
        // return true; // represents passed validation
    //}
}, "failed - your custom message");
```

The arguments to the callback are:

- the current **value** of the validated element
- the **element** to be validated

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            myfield: {
                myRule: true  // instead of remote
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Sparky but I've already tried..just edited my answer

Comment: Oh my god I found here my answer!!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732331/jquery-username-validation?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @user2127377, you have your true & false backwards! If you get a match, that should trigger an error (`return false`).

Comment: Edited. My code anyway was right. I thought i could have found solution...but it still doesn't go! I'd need something to return a boolean from ajax 'success' field to the callback of addMethod....Of course a simple 'return' doesn't function

Comment: @user2127377,  Now that you've swapped your true & false, the logic should work.  If `return` doesn't work from inside the `success` function.  Simply set a flag, and return true or false based on that.

Comment: Thanks but it's the solution i thought worked for me. The problem in your code is that the ajax call is made asynchronously and if it would be also a little bit slower (almost certainly) then normal execution, the variable 'result' remains set to initial value...in your case 'undefined'. validator see undefined as 'false' and for me it means the user is always taken...I really don't know where to crash my head!

Comment: @user2127377, I don't know... however, I already solved your question as it was originally posted.